# How to store output from linux call in Python

Tags: python, sorting, subprocess

I am writing a script to sort a file based on a specific column. I tried calling the 'sort' Linux command for this. The code I am using is:

```
from subprocess import 
path_store = /homes/varshith/maf
input = path_store
field = "-k2"
store_output_in_new_file = ">"
new_path = path_store + "_sort.bed"
sorting = Popen(["sort", field, input, append, new_path], stdout=PIPE)
```

But this doesn't work properly. Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: btw, ">" does not append, it overwrites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use communicate to get the output:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
sorting = Popen(["sort", field, output, append, new_path], stdout=PIPE)
out, err = sorting.communicate()  
print out
```

Or just use `check_output` for python >= 2.7:

```
sorting = check_output(["sort", field, output, append, new_path])
```

If you want to just write the sorted contents you can redirect stdout to a file object:

```
output = "path/to/parentfile"
cmd = "sort -k2 {}".format(output)
with open(new_file,"w") as f:
    sorting = Popen(cmd.split(),stdout=f)
```

Comment: I get an error like:    sort: stat failed: >: No such file or directory

Comment: add your full input to your question, my answer relies on you actually passing the correct commands

Comment: path_store is the variable that contains the path to the file as a string

Comment: And I am actually trying to write the output from sort into the new file.

Comment: ok, as it stands you are trying to sort `>` not the file, one sec I will edit

Comment: So, how do I correct it? The actual Linux command I'm trying to emulate is:    sort -k2 inputfile > output_stored_ina_new_file

Comment: Yes I figured it out! Thanks anyways for the effort :D

Comment: `>>` is the shell redirection operator. The first code example won't work. The last example fails if the filename has a space.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, the question was edited as None of the actual data was supplied, it was a question about how to get output from running Popen not how to write to a file. Also how is  your answer really  different?

Comment: Even the very first revision of the question has `append = ">"`. The first two code examples won't work. My answer works.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, as I have previously said the question was how to get output from Popen which I answered saying to  use communicate,  the OP then replied saying they got an error to which  I replied add your full input to your question, *my answer relies on you actually passing the correct commands *, finally I supplied how to write to a file using stdout which is pretty much exactly what you have in your answer so I really have no idea how you think your answer is so special and mine if flawed.

Comment: Let's simplify: do you understand that the first two code examples in your question fail? Do you understand that the remaining example fails if `output`  filename (that is actually an input) has a space in it?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, the first two examples were supplied without really looking at what the OP was doing as the question  was about how to get output from Popen not how do I do... Do you understand context? Secondly there are no spaces in the OP's path and it was just a quick example provided on how to write to a file using stdout. So in summation, the first part of the answer was based on the OP having  working code and when I actually got the full picture what the OP wanted to do. I provided a way extremely similar to the answer you provided much, much later and after downvoting mine I may add.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian So again I reiterate I don't really see what is so special about your answer and flawed about mine. Also I noticed no downvote for the other answer which does not provide any correct way to write to a file nor correct the OP to say it won't work so I find that a bit surprising  and inconsistent .

Comment: you should not use `Popen(["a", ">", "b"], stdout=PIPE)` to emulate `a > b` shell command.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I did not use it to emulate anything, that was the OP's code which  I corrected using stdout to write to a file when I actually understood what they were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope that `output` and `new_path` are actually strings (I assume so, but it's not clear from what you posted).  But assuming all of that is sorted out:

```
sorting = Popen(...)
sorting_output = sorting.communicate()[0]
```

That should store the contents of the subprocess's standard output to `sorting_output`.

Answer (score 0):

To emulate the shell command:

```
$ sort -k2  /homes/varshith/maf > /homes/varshith/maf_sort.bed
```

i.e., to sort `/homes/varshith/maf` file by the 2nd column and to store the sorted output to `/homes/varshith/maf_sort.bed` file in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

field = '-k2'
input_path  = '/homes/varshith/maf'
output_path = input_path + '_sort.bed'
with open(output_path, 'wb', 0) as output_file:
    check_call(["sort", field, input_path], stdout=output_file)
```

It overwrites the output file. To append to the file instead, use `ab` mode instead of `wb`.